# MySQL - Calculating the total number of room sold exclude cancellation for each date in a particular date range of each category

Tags: sql, mysql

I have booking sample data as follows:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
hotel_id | roomtype_id | status   |  booking_timestamp  | checkin_date | checkout_date
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        | 1           | new      | 2023-02-02 00:15:30 | 2023-02-03   | 2023-02-05
1        | 1           | new      | 2023-02-04 09:10:15 | 2023-02-04   | 2023-02-04
1        | 1           | new      | 2023-02-07 03:00:10 | 2023-02-09   | 2023-02-10
1        | 1           | new      | 2023-02-08 04:10:10 | 2023-02-09   | 2023-02-10
1        | 1           | cancelled| 2023-02-08 10:15:30 | 2023-02-09   | 2023-02-10
2        | 2           | new      | 2023-02-03 06:40:14 | 2023-02-06   | 2023-02-07
2        | 2           | new      | 2023-02-05 08:10:14 | 2023-02-06   | 2023-02-08
```

Each row represent 1 room of a particular room type.  I'm looking for effective way to calculate **the total number of room sold exclude cancellation for each date in a particular date range of each room type in each hotel**.  Let's say the date range that I want is started from `2023-02-01` to `2023-02-12`.  The expected output and explanation should be the following.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
hotel_id | roomtype_id | date       | room_sold
--------------------------------------------------------------
1        | 1           | 2023-02-01 | 0          No new check-in yet
1        | 1           | 2023-02-02 | 0          No new check-in yet
1        | 1           | 2023-02-03 | 1          one room got checked-in (1st row of data)
1        | 1           | 2023-02-04 | 2          another room got check-in (2nd row of data)
1        | 1           | 2023-02-05 | 0          all rooms of this room type got check-out
1        | 1           | 2023-02-06 | 0          No new check-in yet
1        | 1           | 2023-02-07 | 0          No new check-in yet
1        | 1           | 2023-02-09 | 1          2 checked-in but 1 cancelled (row 3 to 5)
1        | 1           | 2023-02-10 | 0          all rooms of this room type got check-out
2        | 2           | 2023-02-01 | 0          No new check-in yet
2        | 2           | 2023-02-02 | 0          No new check-in yet
2        | 2           | 2023-02-03 | 0          No new check-in yet
2        | 2           | 2023-02-04 | 0          No new check-in yet
2        | 2           | 2023-02-05 | 0          No new check-in yet
2        | 2           | 2023-02-06 | 2          2 rooms got checked-in (row 6 and 7)
2        | 2           | 2023-02-07 | 1          1 room checked-out (row 6)
2        | 2           | 2023-02-08 | 0          1 room checked-out (row 7)
2        | 2           | 2023-02-09 | 0          No new check-in yet
2        | 2           | 2023-02-10 | 0          No new check-in yet
2        | 2           | 2023-02-11 | 0          No new check-in yet
2        | 2           | 2023-02-12 | 0          No new check-in yet
```

May I have your advise how to solve this problem?

Comment: *1 | 1 | 2023-02-02 | 1  one room got checked-in (1st row of data)* ??? Check-in in 1st row is `'2023-02-03'` - the room is booked but is NOT checked-in.

Comment: Thanks for cross checking.  You are right.  I editted the expected results and explanation on row 2 and 3 already.

Comment: Again... in output row 4 (date='2023-02-04') you count the room which is checked out today (source row 2).. but in the next row you ignore such room (source row 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 AS (
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MIN(checkin_date), '%Y-%m-01') the_date, MAX(checkout_date) last_date
  FROM test
  UNION ALL
  SELECT the_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY, last_date
  FROM cte1
  WHERE the_date < last_date
),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT hotel_id, roomtype_id
  FROM test
)
SELECT cte2.hotel_id,
       cte2.roomtype_id,
       cte1.the_date, 
       SUM(CASE status WHEN 'new' THEN 1
                       WHEN 'cancelled' THEN -1
                       ELSE 0 
                       END) amount
FROM cte1
CROSS JOIN cte2
LEFT JOIN test ON the_date BETWEEN checkin_date AND checkout_date
              AND (cte2.hotel_id, cte2.roomtype_id) = (test.hotel_id, test.roomtype_id)
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

| hotel_id | roomtype_id | the_date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-02-01 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-02-02 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-02-03 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-02-04 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-02-05 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-02-06 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-02-07 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-02-08 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-02-09 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-02-10 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-02-01 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-02-02 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-02-03 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-02-04 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-02-05 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-02-06 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-02-07 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-02-08 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-02-09 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-02-10 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/elBhRjzI)

If there exists a calendar table which contains the dates range which you need the output to obtain for then use it instead of `cte1` (maybe with according WHERE). Accordingly if you have a table with hotels and rooms identifiers then use it instead of `cte2`.

Answer (score 0):

You should generate a series of dates for the given date range using a `RECURSIVE` and join this series of dates with your booking data. After that, group the joined data by **hotel_id**, **roomtype_id**, and **date**. Lastly, use conditional aggregation to count the number of rooms sold for each date, excluding cancellations:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS (
 SELECT DATE('2023-02-01') AS date
 UNION ALL
 SELECT DATE(date + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
 FROM dates
 WHERE date < '2023-02-12'
)
SELECT
 hotel_id,
 roomtype_id,
 date,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN bookings.status = 'new' THEN 1 END) AS room_sold
FROM dates
LEFT JOIN bookings ON dates.date BETWEEN bookings.checkin_date AND bookings.checkout_date
GROUP BY hotel_id, roomtype_id, date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate a date range list using recursive first, and then join them with the check-in date.

Notes: According to your expected output, I don't calculate the check-out date to the amount, unless the check-in date and check-out date are on the same date.

```
SET @startDate = '2023-02-01',
    @endDate = '2023-02-12';

WITH RECURSIVE cteDate AS (
    SELECT @startDate AS `Date`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_ADD(`Date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS `Date` FROM cteDate
    WHERE DATE_ADD(`Date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= @endDate
),
cteRoom AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT hotel_id, roomtype_id
    FROM tblData
)
SELECT cte.`Date`,
    cteRoom.hotel_id,
    cteRoom.roomtype_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tbl.status = 'new' THEN 1
             WHEN tbl.status = 'cancelled' THEN -1
             ELSE 0 END) AS TotalCheckedInRoom
FROM cteDate cte
CROSS JOIN cteRoom cteRoom
LEFT JOIN tblData tbl
ON ((cte.`Date` >= tbl.checkin_date AND cte.`Date` < tbl.checkout_date)             -- if date = checkout date, don't count
    OR (cte.`Date` = tbl.checkin_date AND tbl.checkin_date = tbl.checkout_date))    -- if checkin = checkout date, count as checked in
    AND cteRoom.hotel_id = tbl.hotel_id
    AND cteRoom.roomtype_id = tbl.roomtype_id
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 2,1,3
```